# The values of custom fields are not available functions.php

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WooCommerce and Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I have a function for calculate my product's discount, like this:

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $discount = floatval(10);
    if(!empty($discount) || $discount != 0){
    $discount *= -1;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('discount', $discount, true, '' );
  } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

It's working, but my discount value is dynamic, so must work with custom fields. When I add this line to the function, I get an empty value:

```
$value = get_field( "text_field" );

if( $value ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

But actually, the custom field is not empty in the WordPress admin panel. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're doing it too early. You need to wrap your code in the necessary hook so that it occurs at the correct time.

Because you don't tell `get_field` the ID of the current post, it needs to know which post to get the field from, and it does this by referencing the global variable `$post`, which gets set when you call `the_post`, or by WP Core early on during a page load.

But if you try to do this before it's set, the function doesn't know what the current post is, and fails. This is what you're seeing in `functions.php`. When `functions.php` is loaded, WordPress hasn't set up the post loop, or queried the database, it's still in the process of loading the theme and plugin files. The earliest event/hook that the `$post` is set, would be the `wp` event, your code runs earlier than this.

So instead, lets refer to the [core load diagram](http://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png), which says it's safe to run code from the `init` hook and onwards. I'm going to suggest using the next hook, `wp_loaded` instead, but change this at your discretion:

```
function karmacoma_206593() {
    $value = get_field( "text_field" );
    if( $value ) {
        echo $value;
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'karmacoma_206593' );
```

Here I've put your code inside a function and told WordPress to call it on the `init` event/hook/action. To make sure it doesn't clash with any other code you have, I've used your username and the ID of this question as the functions name.

Next, we have 2 new issues you're unaware of. First, your `if` statements check could be better. For example, if your value is `false`, your check will fail, even if it's a valid value, so I'm going to improve it by using `empty`:

```
if( !empty( $value ) ) {
```

Secondly, you're outputting the value of this field without any form of escaping. What if the value of the field is a script tag? Lets secure this code by using `esc_html` to strip out any html tags:

```
echo esc_html( $value );
```

Giving us this:

```
function karmacoma_206593() {
    $value = get_field( "text_field" );
    if ( !empty( $value ) ) {
        echo esc_html( $value );
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'karmacoma_206593' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I used your karmacoma_206593 function in my file but still doesn't work. I don't know why my value always empty. Whereas when I put get_field('test_field') in theme file, it works good.

Comment: Yes! Problem is I don't tell post ID, added and fixed! Thank you.