# get_field() with ID in one signal filter not working

Tags: functions, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get_field() using post id in one signal filter, I am getting the value of post id. But for some reason note getting the values of get_field(). I have imported wp-load, but still didn't get the values. Can someone help me regarding this ?

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
//This works for already published posts
//$current_affairs = get_field('current_affairs','3210'); 
//Below does not work
$current_affairs = get_field('current_affairs',$post->ID);
$title = $current_affairs[0]['headline'];
$image = $current_affairs[0]['image'];
$fields['isAndroid'] = true;
$fields['isIos'] = true;
$fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
$fields['isChrome'] = false;
$fields['data'] = array(
    "headline"=> $title,
    "image"=> $image,
    "type" => "news",
    "news_data" => $current_affairs
);
/* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
unset($fields['url']);
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: please check your $current_affairs value by var_dump($current_affairs);

Comment: Yes I checked, it has values. I made another test page and tried fetching data, it worked. But when I am trying to fetch in functions.php, it is not working

Comment: I think this is because you're doing it too early. You need to wrap your code in the necessary hook so that it occurs at the correct time.

Comment: try using get_post_meta() function instead of get_field()

Comment: get_post_meta() didn't work @KrishnaJoshi

Comment: I want to send acf data in additional data in one signal notification, the ID is being fetched but I don't know for what reason the acf data is null @PratikPatel

Comment: Please refer at once **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206593/the-values-of-custom-fields-are-not-available-functions-php**

Comment: Thank you for the reference @PratikPatel, but I want to get post data in one signal notification filter. So I don't think getting in init() or wp_loaded() will help me. :/

Comment: Did you try echoing `$post->ID` to see if the function is getting an id properly?  Or by replacing it with an actual number of a post that does have the data you are pulling?

Comment: @rudtek when I am adding actual number of already published post, it is working and yes $post->ID is working correctly, it gets the post id value. But for some reason get_field() returns empty

Comment: did you solve this, as I'm facing the same issue here?